# Amplitude of sine wave with minimum distorsion

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I have the following operational amplifier implemented in LTSpice. Is 100uV a good value for the amplitude of Vg in order to to minimize output signal distortion? If not, what value should I put for Vg in order to minimize output signal distortion?[image]

Comment: Vg = 0 will minimise output distortion. If you want to define an output distortion, then you can derive a finite value for Vg to get that. Note that Q1/2 have no emitter degeneration resistors. Using them would allow higher Vg for the same amount of output distortion.

Comment: @Neil_UK Vg=0 will give just a flat line in simulations, so this is not a good solution.

Comment: 'Minimise distortion' is not a good question, given that the distortion rises from zero for a zero input, to a finite level for any finite input. Think about the usefulness of your question, and then think about the usefulness of my comment.

Comment: He means: there is no sweet-spot distortion point - any input signal will attract distortion hence zero input signal cannot, by definition produce distortion. You have to apply a signal level and live with the distortion that is produced. More signal = more distortion.

Answer (score 1):

Lets predict a gain, then decide the input voltage.

Ignoring the loading of the output emitter follower(which may dominate), the gain will be

- R_earlyVoltage / reac

and with both those numbers decreasing as current increases, lets just divide

- EarlyVoltage / ThermalVoltage
- 26 volts (assumed) / 0.026 volts (fact)

thus the approximate voltage gain will be 1,000x.

Since 100 uv * 1,000 == 0.1 volt, small compared to rails, 100uv seems good.

==================================

Since Q3 is diode and Q4 is common_emitter operating, I'd expect substantial output DC error.

=====================================

best  ?      It's good enough. Since we have no metrics other than sin_ in to become sin_out, go ahead and explore.

Comment: Theoretical gain it's Av=1500

Comment: So basically 100uV it's the best value for the amplitude, no?